# SQL complex data searching query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I am using c# .NET.

I have 3 fields(Text Boxes) txtName,txtSirname, txtLocation.

My database table is

```
Name      | Sirname  | Location

Steve     | Jobs     | US
Kevin     | Peterson | UK
Haechelle | Gibbs    | South Africa
```

I have one search button. On the click of search button i want to display all the results according to text boxex.

BUT

If all the text boxes are empty i want to display whole table.
If name is empty then it should disply result according to sirname and place.
If sirname is empty then it should display result according to name and place.
If name and sirname is empty... and all the possible combinations.

My problem is that i am not allowed to use if statement in C#. I have to write it in one SQL query only. How should i do it. please direct me.

Comment: That seems a bizarre and arbitrary rule (not using `if` in the C#) - personally I'd push back on that...

Comment: Yeah. I googled it hard but was not able to find. he has told me that it will increase performance.

Comment: he is **very very** wrong about that; this (for example see Jakub's answer) can only lead to **worse** performance.

Comment: Yeah i have seen that but he was asking me that here there are three text boxes(txtName,txtSirname,txtLocation) what will you do if there are ten text boxes. According to him there will be lots of if conditions if we do permutation and combinations of ten text boxes.

Comment: then he isn't coding it right. If there are 10 text boxes there will be 10 (or maybe 11) `if` conditions...

Comment: yeah. he is telling me i should avoid 10 ifs and write a single query for it for performance reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
WHERE     
    ([Name] = @name OR @name IS NULL) OR
    ([Sirname] = @sirname OR @sirname IS NULL) OR
    ([Location] = @location OR @location IS NULL)
```

If your textboxes are empty pass `NULL` as the value of parameters in your query / sproc.

Comment: +1 because it answer the question, but I would **strongly** advise against this in real code; I've seen the optimizer make quite a mess of this type of query. The best approach here is, IMO, simply to build the right query for the job.

Comment: Also, the "outer" `OR`s might want to be `AND`, if it is intended that filling in multiple details *restricts* the search, rather than widening it.

Comment: Thanks dude. this answer (With some modifications) is accepted by him(My team leader). Dont know performancewise correct or incorrect. but still with this answer i m on safer side. Thanks .

Answer (score 3):

> yeah. he is telling me i should avoid 10 ifs and write a single query for it for performance reason

He is quite simply wrong. If you do that via a cobbled together query in the TSQL that copes with every combination, then that query will perform very sub-optimally (and will will particularly vulnerable to the performance pain of parameter-sniffing).

Frankly, I would ignore him, and write the correct query in the C# code - this will be *virtually instantaneous* (as in: microseconds) - where as asking a database server to run a bad TSQL query is **VERY** expensive. For example, here's a complete implementation of a cumulative filter in raw TSQL:

```
static void AppendClause(StringBuilder clause, string tsql)
{
    clause.Append(clause.Length == 0 ? " where " : " and ")
          .Append('(').Append(tsql).Append(')');
}    
static Foo[] SearchFoo(string name, int? age, string region)
{
    var whereClause = new StringBuilder();
    if (name != null) AppendClause(whereClause, "f.Name=@name");
    if (age != null) AppendClause(whereClause, "f.Age=@age");
    if (region != null) AppendClause(whereClause, "f.Region=@region");

    string tsql = "select f.* from Foo f" + whereClause;
    using (var conn = GetConnection())
    { // note I'm using "dapper" here for brevity, but any ADO.NET-based
      // code would suffice
        return conn.Query<Foo>(tsql, new { name, age, region }).ToArray();
    }
}
```

or the same in LINQ:

```
static Foo[] SearchFoo(string name, int? age, string region)
{
    using (var ctx = GetContext())
    {
        IQueryable<Foo> query = ctx.Foos;
        if(name != null) query = query.Where(f => f.Name == name);
        if(age != null) query = query.Where(f => f.Age == age);
        if(region != null) query = query.Where(f => f.Region == region);
        return ctx.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Your colleague is very mistaken. And if he still disagrees, feel free to point him in my direction ;p

Comment: although its not in single SQL query i got the logical idea of appending where clause string from your answer. I will try this code and will show him.

Comment: Marc sir, this is working perfectly but my team leader is so idiot that he is not accepting this way of coding. according to him jakub's way of code whith some modifications which i have submited is correct. Dont now further things. But thanx for help.

Comment: @freelancer that must be vexing. He is, by the way, wrong - pretty easy to demonstrate, by simply looking at the two queries perform under plan diagram, stats-io, stats-timing, and a few others. Oh well.

Comment: Yeah Mar sir, he may be wrong. but i have no alternative other than listening to him.

Comment: @freelancer I disagree - you can also demonstrate real numbers. But that could also be a bit confrontational. Up to you really.

Answer (score 1):

```
select ... from ... where
    name = isnull(nullif(@name, ''), name) and
    sirname = isnull(nullif(@sirname, ''), sirname) and
    location = isnull(nullif(@location, ''), location)
```

Just pass `null` or empty string `""` whenever you want to omit parameter. It assumes that: `@name`, `@sirname` and `@location` are parameters.